# Publicar en un grupo de Facebook con requests/Python sin la API

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import datetime
import json
import logging
import re
import random
import requests
import shutil
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq


def main(username, password, page, imgurURL):

    logging.basicConfig(filename='imgur2fb.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

    session = requests.session()

    uid, dtsg = login(session, username, password)

    grupoID = "580864492030176" #(Fijo)

    postToFacebook(session, dtsg, grupoID, "Prueba 55",uid)


def login(session, username, password):

    '''
    Login to Facebook
    '''

    # Navigate to the Facebook homepage
    response = session.get('https://facebook.com')

    # Construct the DOM
    dom = pq(response.text)

    # Get the lsd value from the HTML. This is required to make the login request
    lsd = dom('[name="lsd"]').val()

    # Perform the login request
    response = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', data={
        'lsd': lsd,
        'email': username,
        'pass': password,
        'default_persistent': '0',
        'timezone': '-60',
        'lgndim': '',
        'lgnrnd': '',
        'lgnjs': '',
        'locale':'en_GB',
        'qsstamp': ''
    })

    '''
    Get the users ID and fb_dtsg token. The fb_dtsg token is required when making requests as a logged in user. It
    never changes, so we only need to grab this token once.

    If the login was successful a cookie 'c_user' is set by Facebook. If the login failed, the 'c_user' cookie
    will not be present. This will raise an exception.
    '''
    try:
        uid = session.cookies['c_user']
        dtsg = re.search(r'(type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="([0-9a-zA-Z-_:]+)")', response.text).group(1)

        dtsg = dtsg[dtsg.find("value")+6:]
        dtsg = dtsg[1:-1]

    except KeyError:
        raise Exception('Login Failed!')

    return uid, dtsg


def postToFacebook(session, dtsg, pageID, message,uID):

    data = {        #'composertags_place_name': '',

          '__a':'1',
          '__af':'iw',
          '__be':'-1',
          '__dyn':'',
          '__pc':'EXP3:DEFAULT',
          '__req':'',
          '__rev':'',
          '__user':uID,

        'album_id':'',  
        'attachment':'',    
        'audience':'',
        'backdated_date[year]':'',
        'backdated_date[month]':'',
        'backdated_date[day]': '',
        'backdated_date[hour]':'',  
        'backdated_date[minute]':'',      
        'boosted_post_config':'',   
        'composer_entry_time':'', #Tenia un valor
        'composer_session_duration':'', # Tenia un valor
        'composer_session_id':'',
        'composer_source_surface':'group',
        'composertags_city':'',
        'composertags_place':'',
        'direct_share_status':'0',
        'fb_dtsg': dtsg,    
        'feed_topics':'',
        'future_date':'',    
        'future_time':'',   
        'is_explicit_place': 'false',
        'is_forced_reshare_of_post':'',
        'is_markdown':'false',
        'is_profile_badge_post':'false',
        'is_q_and_a':'false',
        'is_react': 'true',
        'logging':'', # Tenia un valor
        'multilingual_specified_lang':'',
        'num_keystrokes':'', # Tenia un valor
        'num_pastes':'0',
        'post_surfaces_blacklist':'',
        'privacyx':'',
        'prompt_id':'',
        'prompt_tracking_string':'',
        'ref':'group',
        'scheduled': 'false',
        'scheduled_publish_time':'',
        'sponsor_relationship':'0',
        'target_type':'group',
        'xc_disable_config[xc_disable_link]':'',
        'xc_sticker_id':'0',
        'xhpc_aggregated_story_composer':'false',
        'xhpc_composerid':'', # tenia un valor
        'xhpc_context': 'profile',  
        'xhpc_finch': 'false',
        'xhpc_fundraiser_page':'false',
        'xhpc_ismeta': '1',
        'xhpc_message_text': message,
        'xhpc_message': message,
        'xhpc_modal_composer':'false',
        'xhpc_origintopicfeedid':'',
        'xhpc_publish_type':'1', 
        'xhpc_socialplugin':'false',
        'xhpc_targetid': pageID,
        'xhpc_timeline': 'false',
        'xhpc_topicfeedid':'',
    }

    response = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/ajax/updatestatus.php?av='+str(uID)+'&dpr=1',
                            data=data,

                            headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

try:
    main(username='******', password='*******', page='*****', imgurURL='imgurURL=http://imgur.com/search?q=funny')
except Exception, e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print e
```

Tengo este código en parte hecho por mi, en parte basado en un código para publicar en una página de Facebook que no funciona más. Se loguea bien, da respuesta 200, pero devuelve este mensaje de error al publicar

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"__sf":"iw","error":1367001,"errorSummary":"No se
>   puede publicar en esta biograf\u00eda","errorDescription":"The message
>   could not be posted to this
>   Timeline.","payload":null,"bootloadable":{},"ixData":{},"lid":"6409190691856604279"}

. No quiero usar la API de Facebook por varios motivos, uno es educativo, el otro es que el permiso para publicar en un grupo requiere de revisión por parte de Facebook, mandarles una especie de documentación/video sobre cómo se usa la APP, etc. Lo más probable es que esté fallando en algo de todas las variables posts que tengo que mandar, pero no encuentro que puede ser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, por si alguien le interesa, aquí logré hacer un código que funciona pero sólo para mandar texto, usando la interfaz movil de Facebook que es más simple. Subir con imágenes no lo he logrado todavía. La id del grupo está hardcodeada, se puede sacar haciendo una consulta a alguno de los sitios web que devuelven la id de un grupo con su nombre.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import datetime
import json
import logging
import re
import random
import requests
import shutil
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq


def main(username, password, page):

    logging.basicConfig(filename='imgur2fb.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

    session = requests.session()

    uid, dtsg = login(session, username, password)

    grupoID = "580864492030176" #(Fijo)

    postToFacebook(session, dtsg, grupoID, "Prueba 98765",uid)


def login(session, username, password):

    '''
    Login to Facebook
    '''

    # Navigate to the Facebook homepage
    response = session.get('https://facebook.com')

    # Construct the DOM
    dom = pq(response.text)

    # Get the lsd value from the HTML. This is required to make the login request
    lsd = dom('[name="lsd"]').val()

    # Perform the login request
    response = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', data={
        'lsd': lsd,
        'email': username,
        'pass': password,
        'default_persistent': '0',
        'timezone': '-60',
        'lgndim': '',
        'lgnrnd': '',
        'lgnjs': '',
        'locale':'en_GB',
        'qsstamp': ''
    })

    '''
    Get the users ID and fb_dtsg token. The fb_dtsg token is required when making requests as a logged in user. It
    never changes, so we only need to grab this token once.

    If the login was successful a cookie 'c_user' is set by Facebook. If the login failed, the 'c_user' cookie
    will not be present. This will raise an exception.
    '''
    try:
        uid = session.cookies['c_user']
        dtsg = re.search(r'(type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="([0-9a-zA-Z-_:]+)")', response.text).group(1)

        dtsg = dtsg[dtsg.find("value")+6:]
        dtsg = dtsg[1:-1]

    except KeyError:
        raise Exception('Login Failed!')

    return uid, dtsg


def postToFacebook(session, dtsg, pageID, message,uID):

    data = {
        "[0]":"",   
        "[1]":"",
        "__ajax__":"",  #AYmIVqL7VfighmiRmFWSBGl6Aucepl7b-I5RPZaAyEEk7rT-6UQQ2zOpUe433RwWQaZACpH9gA--j8otSHry0_Kmd6iZtK2QHyufgZ59eoLtwA
        "__dyn":"",#    1KQdAm1mxu4UpwDF3GAgy6K6Acgy6F8mxq2K2i5U9EowRwFzohxO3J0GwywlEf8lwJwsE2xCyoe8hwv9E887u4o2CyUb852i1gw
        "__req":"",#    e
    "__user":"100016215514801",
    "album_fbid":"0",
    "appid":"", 
    "at":"",    
    "backdated_day":"", 
    "backdated_month":"",   
    "backdated_year":"",
    "ch":"",    
    "csid":"",  #b4f44053-0da3-46b8-8c54-782fb428a624
    "fb_dtsg":dtsg, #AQEHse9gjZYA:AQGng01UK1fd
    "freeform_tag_place":"",    
    "fs":"",    
    "internal_extra":"",
    "is_backdated":"",  
    "iscurrent":"", 
    "linkUrl":"",   
    "link_no_change":"",    
    "loc":"{}",
    "m_sess":"",    
    "message":message,# prueba 88
    "npa":"",   
    "npc":"",   
    "npn":"",   
    "npp":"",   
    "npw":"",
    "npz":"",   
    "ogaction":"",  
    "oghideattachment":"",  
    "ogicon":"",    
    "ogobj":"", 
    "ogphrase":"",  
    "ogsuggestionmechanism":"",
    "rating":"0",
    "scheduled_am_pm":"",   
    "scheduled_day":"",
    "scheduled_hours":"",   
    "scheduled_minutes":"", 
    "scheduled_month":"",   
    "scheduled_year":"",
    "sid":"",   
    "source_loc":"composer_group",
    "target":pageID,
    "text_[0]":"",
    "text_[1]":"",  
    "unpublished_content_type":"0",
    "waterfall_id":"988d79257398ec678a8e287046f322ca",  # Esto cambia en cada logueo??
    "waterfall_source":"composer_group"

    }


    response = session.post('https://m.facebook.com/a/group/post/add/?gid='+pageID+'&refid=18',

                            #params=params,
                            data=data,
                            #headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
                            headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

    print response


try:
    main(username='j*****', password='****', page='https://www.facebook.com/groups/linkdelgrupo')
except Exception, e:
    logging.exception(e)
    print e
```